# What tables among these to export to start another web not based on magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am to develop a website based on a php framework, not magento. I would need tables such as products, categories, customers, orders, images and eventually a couple more if there is a need I cant think of now. The problem is that magento has a mindblowing roster of related tables that are confusing and I would not know what to do with them if I am using some other framework like laravel etc. For example

this totally confuses me and I dont know if I need that or what to do with it

```
catalog_product_entity_text 

catalog_product_entity_tier_price 

catalog_product_entity_varchar 

catalog_product_link 

catalog_product_link_attribute
```

I would enormously appreciate an experienced wise tip on which I actually need. And what about the Foreign keys? For example, to link orders table with customers table.

Comment: It may be easier to just export products, customers, orders, etc from Magento admin to csv files and work on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento uses an EAV structure. That means that the Entity (product, category, customer), the Attribute and the Value are saved in separate tables. Every type of value (varchar, text, integer, etc.) has it's own value table.

The models within Magento make it possible to easily merge all data in these tables into one object. And I think that's your best go here. You could either create a custom script to get all these entities and parse them into something you could use in your other application. But that is something that requires some extra developing. The other option, which should work out-of-the-box, is exporting the data from the admin (System > Import/Export > Export). Via this method it's possible to export your products and customers to a CSV, which you could import into your own application by writing a script for it. However, this does not let you export stuff like categories or orders, so if you need those as well, you still need to create a custom script.